# Add additional information with every uploaded image in yii

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I want to upload product images with Yii multipleUploadField, and i want the user to fill an additional field 'position' with every image chosen, so that in the end i can get this model
completed, so far i can upload images and save them no problem, im just stuck with the position field.

```
CREATE TABLE productimage (
    fk_imageId INT NOT NULL, 
    fk_productId INT NOT NULL, 
    position ENUM ('front', 'back')
)

$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'uploadProductImagesForm',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
  'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'), // ADD THIS
));     

$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
          'model'=>$productImages,
              'name' => 'productImages',
              'attribute'=>'images',
              'max'=>5,
              'remove'=>Yii::t('ui','Remove'),
              'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|png', 
              'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', 
              'denied' => 'Invalid file type, allowed types are (jpeg, jpg, png)', 
  ));
?>
<div class="row-submit">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $form = $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: elaborate your question and let us know exactly where you have problem.

Comment: [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

Comment: yes, the problem is simple, the structure of my table requires that with every (picture,product) couple i have to specify a position field so that i get for example ('Sony', 'camera.jpeg', 'front'), but i don't know how to create a form that allow me to specify the position field whenever a user choses an image. i now edited the post so you can view the actual struture of my form. thanks

Comment: This may be gives you hint: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/176/uploading-multiple-images-with-cmultifileupload/